# Importance of Posture in Meditation

Tags: meditation-posture

I'm curious to know: how important is posture during meditation? Could someone meditate on public transport, or while walking in different places? Is there a difference in the necessity of posture between a beginner and an advanced practitioner?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes one can meditate anytime anywhere.  The following might be far reaching example, however,  during Buddha's time Ven. Maha Kassapa was an expert in meditation.  As a matter of fact, he was the **only person** Buddha compared himself to be **equal** in the ability to enter Jhana at any time any posture.

Answer (score 1):

Posture is extremely important however sitting cross-legged is not important. What is important is having a naturally erect spine so the mind is alert & the breathing can flow unrestricted.

When sitting in public transport, sit upright, close your eyes & meditate. Completely let go of any self-consciousness that other people are watching you & know what you are doing. Relax & enjoy.

As for walking meditation, this is something monks do a lot. You should try to learn how to do walking meditation (but not in a busy or dangerous place, such as when crossing a busy street in the city).